# Display UIButton mutually in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'd like to display UIButton only in UITableView at even indexPath.row.

But, UIButton appears in all cells.

```
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(160, 140, 80, 40);
    [button setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell addSubview:button];
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?
 Thanks.

Comment: `[cell.contentView addSubview:button];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First make sure what is the height of the cell :**

You may be facing the issue because of height of button.
It should be more or equal to the Button's height.
Additionally replace your code with this.

```
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 4, 80, 40)];
        [button setTitle:@"BtnName" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but you are doing one very small mistake in it. You are trying to add the button on the `cell` instead of doing that, try to add the button on the `contentView` of the `cell` as follows.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```